# File upload mime-type validation with Laravel 4

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4, mime-types

When I upload a well-formed MP3 file, Laravel 4 tells me it's not `audio/mp3` but `application/octet-stream`, which makes this validation fails:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('trackfile' => Input::file('trackfile')), 
    array('trackfile' => 'required|mimes:mp3')
);

if($validator->fails())
    return 'doesn\'t works because mime type is '.Input::file('trackfile')->getMimeType();
else
    return 'it works!';
```

Why doesn't it upload the file as an `audio/mp3` file ?

(I already added `'files' => true` to the form declaration)

Comment: Maybe a look into vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.php helps. I believe this is where getMimeType() lives.

Comment: What is `array('trackfile' => Input::file('trackfile'))` for ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera to bind the 'trackfile' rules key to the 'trackfile' file input. what do you suggest? even if I'm not sure it's the problem here!

Comment: Remove this first line from rules setup `array('trackfile' => Input::file('trackfile')`.

Comment: I have to specify an input for the validator, I can't just remove this line. Besides, if I put only `Input::file('trackfile')` it tells me that it expects an array and not an object.

Comment: This is not making the validation fail, it's because the `mime_content_type` probably, it's tricky to recognize `mp3` files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit**

Built-in validator was still considering some mp3's as application/octet-stream, wether you converted the original file with this or that software.

I finally used the [MimeReader](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NcL5BLwg) class by user [Shane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042193/shane), which totally works. I'm still wondering why is it so hard to detect a right mime type though.

I implemented it as a validator in Laravel:

- Move `MimeReader.phps` in `app/libraries/MimeReader.php` (watch the extension)
- Extend the Laravel `Validator` (I put it in my `BaseController` constructor)

  ```
  Validator::extend('audio', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
  {
      $allowed = array('audio/mpeg', 'application/ogg', 'audio/wave', 'audio/aiff');
      $mime = new MimeReader($value->getRealPath());
      return in_array($mime->get_type(), $allowed);
  });
  ```
- Add your error message in `app/lang/[whatever]/validation.php` (in my case, the key is `audio`)
- I can now use `audio` as a rule ! Example: `'file' => 'required|audio'`, where `file` refers to `Input::file('file')`

---

Laravel was considering `audio/mpeg` files to be `.mpga` and not `.mp3`. I corrected it in `MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php` (in the Symfony library), along with `audio/ogg` that were considered as `.oga`. Maybe the audio mime-type depends on what software encoder was used.

Other method is to bypass the validator and check the mime-type directly into the controller using `Input::file('upload')->getMimeType()` like Sheikh Heera said.

Comment: +1, Glad you shared the solution, try to describe it properly so it'll be a reference for this kind of problems.

Comment: @Shane's MimeReader domain is down. Any other place where can be found?

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because of `mp3` file's mime type is `audio/mpeg` or could be that, it fails to recognize the `mime_content_type` and tells `application/octet-stream` as a generic/fallback type. You may try this rule (example given below) instead (not tested/sure), because `audio/mpeg` is the correct mime type for `mp3` according to [rfc3003](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003):

```
array('trackfile' => 'required|mimes:audio/mpeg,mp3')
```

Also, you may manually check the `mime` type using something like this:

```
$file = Input::file('upload');
if($file->getMimeType() == 'audio/mpeg') {
    // valid
}
else {
    // invalid
}
```

**Update:**

Specially, for `mp3` files, you may also use a library [getID3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/1.9.7/) which is similar to [Php PECL extension id3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php), if you use it, you will be also able to use `ID3 tag` of the file and can get information such as `title`, `artist`, `album`, `year`, `genre` etc.

If you use it, you have to download it manually from the given link (`getid3`) and put it in a folder inside `app`, maybe `app/libs/` and just put the `getid3` folder from the extracted source into the `libs` folder then in your `composer.json` file add an entry inside `classmap` of `autoload` section like:

```
// ...
"app/tests/TestCase.php",
"app/libs/getid3"
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload` from terminal/command prompt and you are ready to use it. To use it symply try this:

```
$file = Input::file('upload'); // assumed name of the file input is upload
$path = $path = $file->getRealPath();
$id3 = new getID3();
$tags = $id3->analyze($path);
if(is_array($tags) && array_key_exists('audio', $tags)) {
    // valid
    dd($tag['tags']);
}
```

For a valid `mp3` file You'll get an array like this:

```
array (size=2)   'id3v1' => 
    array (size=6)
      'title' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '46. Piya Basanti' (length=16)
      'artist' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '(Freshmaza.com)' (length=15)
      'album' =>
      ...
```

If you have already installed or can install the `PECL` extension using (from terminal) following command:

```
pear install pecl/id3
```

Then you may normally use

```
$tags = id3_get_tag( "path/to/example.mp3" );
print_r($tag);
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [title] => DN-38416
    [artist] => Re:\Legion
    [album] => Reflections
    [year] => 2004
    [genre] => 19
)
```

Check [Php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php).

Comment: I solved the issue. Specifying `audio/mpeg` in the validator didn't work, I had to do it in the mime-type guesser file directly. Thank you for your time and the additional comment about ID3 tags though! I'll surely look into it.