# How to add a mime type in Laravel Validator

Tags: php, validation, symfony, laravel

I can not figure out how to add a mime type before validation. I need to upload CSV files however they have the mime type text/x-comma-separated-values so how can I add that mime type to the MimeTypeExtensionGuesser array? I would like to keep things simple in my Controller method and just have:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
'file' => 'required|mimes:csv'
]);
```

but first I need to add the new mime type.

Comment: Possible solution from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21611390/385265

Comment: I have considered the Validator::extend option but it seems dirty. If there is no other way then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mime = Input::file('file')->getMimeType();//returns text/plain

    //check if file is csv

    if($mime != 'text/plain'){

        $error = array();
        $error[] = "File type must be csv";
        $validator = $error;
        return Redirect::to('your-page')->withErrors($validator);
    }
```