# Image mime type is different based on which PHP Server I use

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this image file that when I test in my local environment then PHP determines it is of type

```
image/jpeg
```

However that same code and same image on my server gets detected as

```
application/octet-stream
```

What could be causing this behavior?

```
Image Size: 2.31 MB 
Name: ^EC91F66F648FD45E7BF3BE9D2169E239D41E49B794EA71E326^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr (1).jpg
```

**Local Environment**

```
PHP: 5.6.15
```

**Live Environment**

```
PHP: 5.6.9
```

Comment: needs example code, which function returns the mime?

Comment: How are you testing the image type? some methods rely on a system magic file.

Comment: I'm using Laravel Filesystem It's used like so
Input::file('img')->getMimeType()

https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/6ba03aaf656809bd5c5264a8d38171efafbe92ee/FilesystemAdapter.php#L204 which I beleive is essentially this http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getMimeType
I'm just surprised it works fine in the local dev environment but on the live server it's octet stream. Could it be due to some other php config like max file size and if its higher than a specific size it's handled differently by php? guessing...

Comment: A similar problem was mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564029/file-upload-mime-type-validation-with-laravel-4 If you are only using images check out the Intervention package for Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to a difference with the mime magic file. This file contains sequences that help detect which mime type a file is by reading the first few bytes.

The fileinfo class, which is being used with your methods, can be given a path to the magic file, otherwise it has a process of searching for a mime magic file.

If you want to set a specific magic file you can add this setting to your php.ini `mime_magic.magicfile`.

Comment: Before you check the mime type, are you checking that the upload completed successfully? You may be checking an empty file.

Comment: Larvel is simply abstracting these error message: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php, You are hitting UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE in this case.