# Why does laravels guessExtension() method say that my mp3 file is bin?

Tags: php, laravel, extension-methods

I'm trying to upload an mp3 file with laravel. And when I do

```
dd(Input::file('mp3')->guessExtension());
```

It gives me back "**bin**" in a string with certain mp3 files. With other files this is correct, and it is giving me back 'mpga'. 
What does this "**bin**" as extension mean?

This file doesn't go through my validation now when I do this rule :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'mp3'      => 'required|mimes:mpga|max:500',
           ]);
```

When I dump my request it says that the mimetype is mpga , but still it comes back with an error: *'file must be of type mpga'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug your files using services like

http://mime.ritey.com/

and check if there is any error in validator

`if ($validator -> passes()) {
    // passes
} else {
    dd($validator->errors()->all()); 
}`

If validator is not working as you expect you can try using another validator like http://pastebin.com/raw/NcL5BLwg

Read here: [File upload mime-type validation with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564029/file-upload-mime-type-validation-with-laravel-4)

Answer (score 8):

To answer one of your questions, 'bin' is returned for octet streams:

```
// Part of the MimeTypeExtensionGuesser class
'application/octet-stream' => 'bin',
```

Laravel uses Symfony File and Symfony File uses [built-in PHP's finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to guess the mime type.

Therefore, your question becomes – why finfo detects some of your MP3 files as application/octet-stream? There is a possibility that something is slightly wrong about this specific MP3 file, given that other files pass.

By the way, try in a shell:

```
$ file -I file.mp3 
file.mp3: audio/mpeg; charset=binary
```

See if you get correct response.