# laravel check file extension in upload form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, php-7

this is the html form:

```
<form method = "post" action="...">
   <input type="text" name="subject" />
   <input type="file" type="files['new']['file']"/>
   <input type="text" type="files['new']['name']"/>
</form>
```

Now I try read in server (laravel).

```
   public function chechkForm(request $request){
      $input = $request->all();
      dd(input['files']['new']['file' );
   }
```

the result is:

```
UploadedFile {#1356 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "GK-Footer-Logo.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Temp"
  filename: "phpC3BF.tmp"
  basename: "phpC3BF.tmp"
```

Now I try these to print mimetype:

> $input['new0']['content']['mimeType']

or

> $input['new0']['content']->mimeType

or

> $input['new0']['content']->mimeType()

what is my wrong? I get for all of them 'error'!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload mime-type validation with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564029/file-upload-mime-type-validation-with-laravel-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to know the extension and mime-type

you can use getClientOriginalExtension method and getClientMimeType

or other you wanna use you can find it here [other methods](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php)

simple usage and more laravel way

the form you can set up like this

```
<form method = "post" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
... other input ...
<input type="file" name="picture"/>
.... other input ....
</form>
```

in controller you can process with helper file('field_name');

```
public function checkForm(Request $request){
  $file = $request->file('picture');
  dd( $file->getClientOriginalExtension() );
  dd( $file->getClientMimeType() );

}
```